# Problems installing extdirect on the django project

Tags: python, django, extjs

I installed the django project in python 3.6 and I want to use extjs 6 for server and client interaction.

As a basis, I took an article written by the user "k0smita" - https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130149-Samples-Examples-for-ExtJS-4-0-and-Django.

After creating and configuring the django project, I added the `extdirect.django` package using pycharm.
In the settings.py file, INSTALLED_APPS added 'extdirect.django', and when the application is launched, an error is produced first

> module is not installed 'decorators'.

To fix this, I installed the decorators package and now I get an error:

> ImportError: can not import name 'remoting'.

In the requirements.txt file I have the following:

```
decorators == 0.1.1
Django == 1.11.15
extdirect == 0.4
extdirect.django == 0.3
pytz == 2018.5
```

Why can an error "ImportError: can not import name 'remoting'" occur while the decorators package is installed on my project?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. `decorators` module is available via `from extdirect.django import decorators`, `remoting` via `from extdirect.django.decorators import remoting`, so you don't need to install `decorators` package which is not relevant and should be uninstalled to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: The last [`extdirect`](https://pypi.org/project/extdirect/) release was in 2010 - it looks as if it does not support Python 3. It probably does not support modern releases of Django either. I would avoid using this library in your project.